# most effective way to find positions of repeated values php

Tags: php

I would like to the most effective way to get the position of repeated elements element in array. For example, if i have:

`$example = array('a','b','c','a','a','d');`

So in this case 'a' is at position 0 - 3 - 4.

I know we can loop through but i think in it is ineffective. I would be grateful if you could show me a better way to do this.

Thank you very much

Comment: A loop is the ONLY way. Even if you found some built in function to do what you want, it would be looping over the array.

Comment: Thank you very much. @Jonathan I just want to find out the best way to do this it is so unnecessary to down vote my question but thanks anyway..

Comment: @JonathanKuhn your not wrong but the complied php function loop is going to be faster than witting your own

Comment: @Dagon, I am aware of that. However, in all cases here you will need to loop unless you know what keys have duplicates.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn its cool bro, his particular needs and concerns are not clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

array_keys() with the optional search_value parameter

```
$example = array('a','b','c','a','a','d');

print_r(array_keys($example, "a"));
```

output:

```
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 3 [2] => 4 )
```

---

If you don't have a particular vlaue in mind and want  the positions of all the values:

```
$example = array('a','b','c','a','a','d');



$out=array();
foreach($example as $k=>$v){

  $out[$v][]=$k;

}
echo '<pre>';

print_r($out);
```

returns:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 4
        )

    [b] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [c] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

    [d] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
        )

)
```

Comment: Only problem is that it requires you to know the values first.

Comment: i interpreted as he did, as he specified a

Comment: The second option is what I was thinking should be done.

Comment: yheah, i still don't know 100% what he actually wants so --- both options are open to him

Comment: Thank you very much guys. The first option is exactly what i want because i dont know all php array function. Thanks again